# outerHTML/innerHTML on #text node

Tags: javascript

```js
var range = document.createRange();



//start range at a point somewhere in the first #text node
range.setStart(document.getElementById('my_textarea').childNodes[0], 4);

//end range outside of span
range.setEnd(document.getElementById('my_textarea').childNodes[2], 0);


range.startContainer.innerHTML = "hi";
```

```html
<div id="my_textarea" contenteditable>
000000000<span id="test_span" style="font-weight:bold;">000000000</span>
</div>
```

I have a range and I would like to insert an opening span tag in the startContainer at startOffset. I am unsure of how to even alter the html of the startContainer. My problem may be arising because startContainer is #text which is a weird browser implementation, not sure. The following code has no effect:

```
range.startContainer.outerHTML = "<b>This is an example of modifying the startContainers outerHTML</b>";
```

This does not produce the expected results. I have a codepen however the issue may be a little difficult to recreate if your not familiar with the code and also it may only work in firefox, have yet to test it in other browsers.

https://codepen.io/justinhdevelopment/pen/GRZzEom

Sorry about all the if statements but the area of interest would be:

```
  } //End for loop
    }else if(range.commonAncestorContainer == textarea && (range.startContainer.nodeName === "#text" && range.endContainer.nodeName === "#text")){
    if(range.startContainer.parentNode.nodeName === "SPAN"){ console.log("Start Container Parent Node is SPAN");}else{ 
    console.log("OOOOOOOOOOOOOMMMMMMMGGGGGGGGG");
```

To recreate the problem, type a string (example: 00000000000000000000000) highlight a portion of the end and click bold. Then highlight another portion of the end that contains the bold part as well as non bold text ( the point here is to make a selection that fully contains the bold span and also contains non styled text) This will set the commonAncestorContainer to the textarea and the start and end container to #text node. Now with this Range I can splice in an opening span tag and end tag, but I can't seem to alter the HTML of the startContainer. I apologize if I dont make sense, but if any clarification is needed I will gratefully explain. Thank you for your help and time.

Comment: Pen updated, sorry it was an older version

Comment: Please include a [mre] in the question itself, not only on an external site. You can use [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552) (icon looks like `<>` in the editor toolbar) for HTML/CSS/JS snippets.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have updated my question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Since the text node doesn't contain any HTML, outerHTML does nothing for the text node.

Consider using a span instead.

```js
var span = document.getElementById("span");

span.outerHTML = '<span class="blue">changed!</span>'
```

```css
.blue {
color: blue;
}
```

```html
<body style="font-family:sans-serif;margin:0">
<p>Let's change <span id="span">this</span> word blue.</p>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. This would not work in my case because all I am wanting to add is an opening tag, the closing tag will be added similarly to the ranges endContainer

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the methods available on [`Range`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Range), it seems like what you want to do is [`deleteContents()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Range/deleteContents), then [`insertNode()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Range/insertNode) to add your new text.

```js
var range = document.createRange();

//start range at a point somewhere in the first #text node
range.setStart(document.getElementById('my_textarea').childNodes[0], 4);

//end range outside of span
range.setEnd(document.getElementById('my_textarea').childNodes[2], 0);

range.deleteContents();
range.insertNode(document.createTextNode("hi"));
```

```html
<div id="my_textarea" contenteditable>
000000000<span id="test_span" style="font-weight:bold;">000000000</span>
</div>
```

---

If, however, you just want to surround the contents of the range with a tag, use [`surroundContents()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Range/surroundContents)

```js
var range = document.createRange();

//start range at a point somewhere in the first #text node
range.setStart(document.getElementById('my_textarea').childNodes[0], 4);

//end range outside of span
range.setEnd(document.getElementById('my_textarea').childNodes[2], 0);

var newSpan = document.createElement("span");
newSpan.classList.add("red");

range.surroundContents(newSpan);
```

```css
.red { color: red; }
```

```html
<div id="my_textarea" contenteditable>
000000000<span id="test_span" style="font-weight:bold;">000000000</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. This isn't quite the answer I am looking for since surroundContents would surround the range encapsulating the full #text node whereas I would like to only add an opening tag at the startOffset of the #text node (range.StartContainer)

Comment: But I think it will need to be something like this because you cannot manually create an element in javascript right?

Comment: When I click Run code snippet in Edge, it shows the first three 0s of the text node as black, indicating that the start tag of the added `span` is towards the start of the text node (that is, at the start of `range`). Perhaps you could be more clear on how that differs from what you want?

Answer (score 0):

Range.surroundContents()
is the correct answer due to the inability to bypass the node insertion method javascript uses to manipulate the DOM.

surroundContents will not work if your range endContainer or startContainer is a sub-child of the commonAncestorContainer. So you will need to use setStartBefore and setEndAfter to properly surround the range.